# Layout displays differently on emulator and android than it should

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

The layout is displayed differently in the design and differently in the emulator and on the android. I am new and i cant figure out why is it.

[image]

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your login"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.099"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your password"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your email"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailWarrning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:text="fwef"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passwordWarrning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="duap"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/password"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="316dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Female" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Shemale" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:text="Set your sex:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

while learning from youtube, I still face problems with some strange problems, despite the fact that I am doing it step by step as in the tutorial

Comment: can you please share your xml layout

Comment: share your xml code . it probably has to do with your xml code. you can edit the question and paste your xml code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Kerg3r! This forum is solely about coding, so when posting a question make sure you include some code in your question if it is relevant. With posting an image of the layout preview, we can only guess what the problem could be and not help you effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You see the difference between design view and emulator as screen size is different. RadioGroup is shifting up because of `android:layout_marginBottom="316dp"`.Remove this hard margin and add top constraint for RadioGroup so that its always below textView6 .

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

Also adjust textView6 constraints so that its always  below email view.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:text="Set your sex:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Add some margin between email and textView6 if you wish.

Also remove top margins for emailWarning and passwordWarning and align these views to email and password views by changing constraints as below .

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailWarrning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fwef"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/email" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passwordWarrning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="duap"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/password"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/password" />
```